# What is a currently a good game stack for simple Javascript 2D multiplatform game?

Tags: 2d, javascript, svg

I'm looking for advice from someone can help me avoid common pitfalls in developing light weight, quick-to-market games. Yeah, I've heard of Google ;-), but a trip down Google lane does not beat solid experience from someone who has been down this path. I'm looking for advice from someone who works alone, or in a small team, and has developed some 2D games for mobile.

My game ideas don't require intensive graphics, just simple arcade style glyphs and collision detection. My experience is mostly with Scala, Java and web technologies (Javascript, CSS, SVG, HTML, etc).

My question is: Is there a nice stack that someone can suggest that will be a good fit for my skillset?

I'm considering Javascript for simple 2D shooter games with simple multiplayer games being supported with a Scala server-side written on [Spray](https://github.com/spray/spray). Is this silly? Should I rather look into things such as Unity 3D, and use it in 2D mode?

For the actual game engine, something like the [Sparrow Framework](http://gamua.com/sparrow/) would be great, but it needs to be multiplatform.

Comment: I don't know if you've had a look at this before, but libgdx http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ is a good cross-platform games library that uses Java. It can deploy on to Andriod, Desktop and HTML5, without needing to edit the core code of your game.

Comment: +1 for libgdx!  I'm a complete, complete noob, and I was able to get a game up and running with proper input and music within like a week using libgdx.  And like BigStuuu said, it easily deploys to Android, desktop, AND HTML5.

Comment: Thanks @BigStuuu and CptSupermrkt. I'm currently going through the libgdx tutorials. It looks really promising.

Comment: What's a "stack"?

Comment: @Bane, a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack) is basically any grouping of software for solving a specific problem. For instance, [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) = Linux/Apache/MySQL/(PHP/Perl/Python), a stack used for web servers.

Comment: I think this question is too subjective and localised for GameDev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CreateJS](https://createjs.com/) is a Javascript library for working with Canvas and other HTML5 web stuff like audio. It's not a game engine but it can definitely be used to [make games](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davrous/html5-gaming-animating-sprites-in-canvas-with-easeljs).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Mosync.](http://www.mosync.com/) If you can work with HTML5 technologies (like Canvas), it may be just what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately Mosync does not have any game developer API's, such as Box2D etc.

Comment: What kind of physics do you need? In your question you said you only needed simple collision checks, you don't need an API to do this. And you certainly don't need a "game dev API" to do a simple 2D shooter.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't specify this in my last answer since the question explicitly mentions Javascript in the title. However, since you have Java development experience: [playN](http://code.google.com/p/playn/) would be the way to go! Take a look.